# Azure AKS virtual node and daemon set

Tags: azure, newrelic, azure-aks

We are currently running AKS k8s cluster. this cluster is using a virtual node which is to handle bursting load when request/second reaches a specific limit.
we are also trying to explore APM tools like new-relic.new relic provide integration with k8s by daemon set.

**query**
as per my understanding daemon set run on each node. 
what will be the case for virtual node and daemon set? 
will daemon set run 24 by 7 on the virtual node, if yes then how to reduce cost and monitor pods running on a virtual node?

Answer (score 0):

`DaemonSet`s are currently not supported via AKS virtual node (as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes#limitations))